# How to change the volume of a wav resource using NAudio?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, naudio, wave

In my application I play two sound files they are Wave files, two resources, one for a "Success" action and the other for "Error" ocurred.

So for play them I do this:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Success, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

Now I want to add an option in my app to modify the volume of that wavefiles, I mean to play them with less volume than the original volume (if the user want to do that).

I Googled it for Naudio and other StackOverFlow questions like mine and I've noticed the NAudio library can do this job, the problem is all the samples are in C#, also are ultra professional coded so really I did not understand how I can change the volume of my wav files.

I'm working in VB.NET.

If you need additional information then here is the NAudio lib: http://naudio.codeplex.com/releases/view/96875

And here is the interesting part of the DemoApp of NAudio, I think here is how the volume is increased or decreased ...but I'm not sure:

```
        namespace NAudioDemo.AudioPlaybackDemo

        this.fileWaveStream = plugin.CreateWaveStream(fileName);
        var waveChannel =  new SampleChannel(this.fileWaveStream, true);
        this.setVolumeDelegate = (vol) => waveChannel.Volume = vol;
        waveChannel.PreVolumeMeter += OnPreVolumeMeter;

        var postVolumeMeter = new MeteringSampleProvider(waveChannel);
        postVolumeMeter.StreamVolume += OnPostVolumeMeter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended Solution:

```
#Region " NAudio "

Public Class NAudio_Helper

' [ NAudio ]
'
' // By Elektro H@cker
'
' Instructions:
' 1. Add a reference for the "NAudio.dll" file into the project.
'
' Examples:
'
' Dim Stream As NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader = New NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(File)
'
' Set_Volume(Stream, 0.5)
' Play_Sound(Stream, 1)
' Play_Sound(My.Resources.AudioFile)
' Play_Sound("C:\File.wav")


' Play Sound (File)
Private Sub Play_Sound(ByVal File As String, _
                       Optional ByVal Volume As Single = Nothing)

    Dim Wave As New NAudio.Wave.WaveOut

    Select Case File.Split(".").Last.ToLower
        Case "aiff"
            Wave.Init(New NAudio.Wave.AiffFileReader(File))
        Case "mp3"
            Wave.Init(New NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(File))
        Case "wav"
            Wave.Init(New NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(File))
        Case Else
            Wave.Init(New NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(New NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader(File))))
    End Select

    If Not Volume = Nothing Then Wave.Volume = Volume
    Wave.Play()

End Sub

' Play Sound (MemoryStream)
Private Sub Play_Sound(ByVal Stream As IO.MemoryStream, _
                       Optional ByVal Volume As Single = Nothing)

    Dim Wave As New NAudio.Wave.WaveOut
    Wave.Init(New NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(New NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(Stream))))
    If Not Volume = Nothing Then Wave.Volume = Volume
    Wave.Play()

End Sub

' Play Sound (Unmanaged MemoryStream)
Private Sub Play_Sound(ByVal Stream As IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream, _
                       Optional ByVal Volume As Single = Nothing)

    Dim Wave As New NAudio.Wave.WaveOut
    Wave.Init(New NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(New NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(Stream))))
    If Not Volume = Nothing Then Wave.Volume = Volume
    Wave.Play()

End Sub

' Play Sound (NAudio Stream)
Private Sub Play_Sound(ByVal NAudio_Stream As Object, _
                       Optional ByVal Volume As Single = Nothing)

    Dim Wave As New NAudio.Wave.WaveOut
    Wave.Init(NAudio_Stream)
    If Not Volume = Nothing Then Wave.Volume = Volume
    Wave.Play()

End Sub

' Set Volume (NAudio Stream)
Private Function Set_Volume(ByVal NAudio_Stream As Object, ByVal Volume As Single) _
As NAudio.Wave.WaveOut

    Dim Wave As New NAudio.Wave.WaveOut
    Wave.Init(NAudio_Stream)
    Wave.Volume = Volume
    Return Wave

End Function

End Class

#End Region
```

Comment: WaveOut.Volume is now deprecated.  This answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get hold of your resource as a Stream, then you can use a `WaveFileReader` to load it, and then pass that into a `SampleChannel` to allow you to adjust the volume. `MeteringSampleProvider` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks but I could only follow the first step: Public wavefile As New NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader("C:\Success.wav"), I don't know how is the next step to do.

Comment: the next step is the same as shown in your question - pass it into a SampleChannel constructor. Then make sure you pass that samplechannel into your WaveOut to be played, or setting its volume will have no effect